# Constantly Reading From Memory Address

Tags: c++, winapi

In my program I have to constantly (every 1-6s) read values from given memory addresses. My question is, "What is the best way to achieve this?" Should I just create a loop with ReadProcessMemory? Is there a better method?

Comment: can you add the context ? the brut answer is "there is not magic better method".

Comment: Once every second is not very often (for a modern computer). Not even on a modest small embedded system is it very often. So I would say that the "best" way is the way you already know.

Comment: I'm not really sure what I should add for context. My program reads memory addresses to obtain values assigned by another program. It will then utilize the information obtained to perform an assigned process.

Comment: you can look into inter-process communication, perhaps use a socket to send values.

Comment: Every 1 to 6 seconds is an eternity for a CPU. I'd do it with a sleep-read cycle in a separate thread. You'd also probably want to mark the variable you'd read the value into as volatile.

Comment: @VladDinev [Commander Data concurs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6xijhqU8r2A).

Comment: aren't you worried about consistency?

Comment: @user4581301 lol

Comment: added Windows API tag as the question suggests it is about that

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to read from memory constantly is to call ReadProcessMemory() in a loop and using Sleep()

```
while (true)
{
    //ReadProcessMemory(...);
    Sleep(3000);
}
```

This will call ReadProcessMemory() once every 3 seconds approximately.

A better method would be to get the current take, before and after reading memory and seeing if the time that has passed is longer than 3 seconds before reading memory again, this way you are not sleeping an entire thread.